# How to feed Winamp vis plugins with data?

Tags: plugins, winamp

Does anybody have any idea what is the right way to feed sound data to Winamp visualisation plugin, so it could produce nice output? I succeded in feedin it the wrong way. Plugin is producing output, but it does not follow the music.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the visualization only follows winamp's sound output. You can change it to use an external audio source.

1. Goto the menu: Play > Location
2. Type: `linein://` (make sure line-in is selected as the recording source for your OS)
3. Start the input sound source
4. Start the visualization!